# How are data in tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist formatted?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow, mnist

I am analyzing a sample code that implements a Restricted Boltzmann Machine (RBM) using Tensorflow. The input data seems to be the good old MNIST, except that apparently, it is now available in `Tensorflow` itself.

So, instead of running this sample code on MNIST, I want to run it on my own data. But the problem is that I do not know how

> tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist

has been formatted. Is it like a `CSV` file? If I want to feed my own data, which comes from Wizemann's horse images, how should I format my data that is compatible with how MNIST has been formatted?

I'm very new to this stuff. So, please enlighten me if I am mistaken or my question is absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/get_started/mnist/beginners) after loading the data,

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
```

You can use the following line,

```
mnist.train.images.shape
```

to see the shape of images, as you can see it is a rank-2 matrix which means images are unrolled which one dimension specifies the number of examples and another specifies the number of pixels __features.

Comment: Thanks. But this only says what the shape of the training data look like. If I'm not mistaken, tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist also contains training labels, test data and test labels. Even though I do not need labels because RBMs are unsupervised, but I still would like to know how I can make a bundle out of my data like this. I hope my question is clear.

Comment: @stressedout it is not a csv file, it is a matrix of values. If I've understood your question, you want to change the inputs but you want to know how the inputs are.

Comment: You're right. I don't want to overcomplicate it for myself at this point, so even though I still have questions about how MNIST data are stored and read, I'll leave that for another time. I'll play with my code and try to get it working. Thanks.